# Question about why inertia subgroup is a closed subgroup of the Galois group

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field, profinite-groups

Let $K$ be a local field complete with discrete valuation $v$ with finite residue field $k$. 
I am just wondering how does one know that the the inertia subgroup $I_v$ is a closed subgroup of $Gal(\overline{K}/K)$?

And if it talks about finite quotient $I_v/J$ may I assume automatically that $J$ is a closed subgroup of $I_v$?

I am asking this question because it came up in the book I am reading and the book doesn't talk about this stuff... Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mathmo123 ahhh, I see. thanks. And if the book just immediately talks about $I_v/J$ is it implicitly implied that $J$ is a closed subgroup of $I_v$ in general? would you happen to know?

Comment: There are finite index subgroups of $I_v$ that aren't closed: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128596/are-finite-index-subgroups-of-inertia-closed. It depends on $J$.

Comment: (In Mathmo123's above comment, "which has the discrete topology" seems to be wrong and unnecessary to me).

Comment: @Mathmo123 $Gal(\bar k/k )$ admits profinite topology, not discrete. But you can see $\{0\}$ is closed by Hausdorff.